# How to perform navigation from UIView to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

In my home screen have multiple sections of `UICollectionView` so I used separate - separate views(`xib`) for each section(`UICollectionView`s) now I have to perform navigation(`didSelectItemAt`) I am unable to perform it even no error is there

I user below code for navigation(`didSelectItemAt`)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "ProductListing", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProductListingViewController") as? ProductListingViewController
    (superview?.next as? ProductListingViewController)?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)}
```

Comment: Never do `(superview?.next as? ProductListingViewController)?`. Use a delegate protocol, closure or notification (depending on your use case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `callbacks` for this.

In your `collectionView View` add this callBack :

```
var didSelectCallback: (() -> Void)?
```

Then in `didSelectItem` delegate method of `collectionView` write this :

```
if let callBack = didSelectCallback {
   callBack()
}
```

Then in controller when you add this `collectionView View` add this callBack :

```
yourView.didSelectCallback = { [weak self] in 
   guard let weakSelf = self else {return}
   let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "ProductListing", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProductListingViewController") as? ProductListingViewController
   weakSelf.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way will send callback from view to ViewController and perform navigation from it like this:

```
class View: UIView {
     var didTapSomething: () -> Void
}
```

and in ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var view: View!

    override func viewDidload() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       view.didTapSomething = {
          //perform navigation
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ProductListing", bundle: nil)
let productListingVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProductListingViewController")
self.present(productListingVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I already used this aproch giving an error self.present not a member or UIView Class (Value of type 'PopularProducts' has no member 'present')